# Usar modal para confirmar si se crear un usuario

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de que salga una ventana modal que confirme si se quiere o no registrar un usuario,estoy usando php para hacer que este se agregue, la ventana de modal sale pero al darle click al boton de guardar, este no hace nada, aqui les dejo el codigo

Este es el codigo de mi formulario

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card col-md-6">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <form method="post" id="f" action="add_user.php">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Cedula</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cedula" name="cedula" placeholder="Cedula" required onkeypress="return valida(event)" minlength="7">
                    <div id="Info"></div>
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                     <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Nombre</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="full-name" name="full-name" placeholder="Nombre completo" required onkeypress="return letras(event)">
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                     <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Usuario</span>
                    </div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" required>
                      <div id="nfo"></div>
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                     <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Contraseña</span>
                    </div>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name ="password"  placeholder="Contraseña" required minlength="8">
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                     <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Rol de Usuario</span>
                    </div>
                      <select class="form-control" id="level" name="level" required>
                        <option value="">Selecciona el tipo de usuario</option>
                        <?php foreach ($groups as $group ):?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $group['group_level'];?>"><?php echo ucwords($group['group_name']);?></option>
                      <?php endforeach;?>
                      </select>
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                     <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Status Usuario</span>
                    </div>
                      <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status" required>
                        <option value="">Selecciona el status del usuario</option>
                         <option value="1">Activo</option>
                        <option value="0">Inactivo</option>
                      </select>
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="form-group clearfix" style="float: right;">
                    <button type="submit" id="ad" name="add_user" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" >Crear</button>
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                </div><!-- ./col -->
              </form>
            </div><!-- ./panel-body -->
          </div><!-- ./panel default -->
        </div><!-- ./card-body -->
      </div><!-- /.card -->
    </div><!-- /.col -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!--/. container-fluid -->
```

y este es el codigo de mi modal

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">¿Esta seguro de crear el usuario?</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Compruebe que los datos son correctos antes de crear el usuario
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Crear Usuario</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hola @Mar, que quieres que aparezca en el modal =>? el formulario de inscripcion ?

Comment: Hola @srJJ no, lo que quiero es que el modal sea como una ventana de confirmacion, que el usuario cuando le de al boton de crear salga ese modal y luego cuando le de al boton de crear usuario es que todos los datos metidos en el formulario se guarden en la base de datos

Answer (score 1):

Revisando tú código veo  que tu botón **Crear Usuario** no tiene un **id** ni **clase**, lo cual es importante para trabajar con JavaScript, He añadido una clase al mismo con el nombre de **btnCrear** y añadí un **script** que enviara tu formulario (al cual le puse un **id="form1"**) al momento de confirmar. Espero te ayude.

```js
 $(".btnCrear").click(function(){
   $("form").submit();
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card col-md-6">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <form method="post" id="f" action="add_user.php">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Cedula</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cedula" name="cedula" placeholder="Cedula" required onkeypress="" minlength="7">
                    <div id="Info"></div>
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                     <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Nombre</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="full-name" name="full-name" placeholder="Nombre completo" required onkeypress="">
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                     <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Usuario</span>
                    </div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" required>
                      <div id="nfo"></div>
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                     <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Contraseña</span>
                    </div>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name ="password"  placeholder="Contraseña" required minlength="8">
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                     <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Rol de Usuario</span>
                    </div>
                      <select class="form-control" id="level" name="level" required>
                        <option value="">Selecciona el tipo de usuario</option>
                        <?php foreach ($groups as $group ):?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $group['group_level'];?>"><?php echo ucwords($group['group_name']);?></option>
                      <?php endforeach;?>
                      </select>
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                     <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Status Usuario</span>
                    </div>
                      <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status" required>
                        <option value="">Selecciona el status del usuario</option>
                         <option value="1">Activo</option>
                        <option value="0">Inactivo</option>
                      </select>
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="form-group clearfix" style="float: right;">
                    <button type="submit" id="ad" name="add_user" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" >Crear</button>
                  </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                </div><!-- ./col -->
              </form>
            </div><!-- ./panel-body -->
          </div><!-- ./panel default -->
        </div><!-- ./card-body -->
      </div><!-- /.card -->
    </div><!-- /.col -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!--/. container-fluid -->

 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">¿Esta seguro de crear el usuario?</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            Compruebe que los datos son correctos antes de crear el usuario
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnCrear">Crear Usuario</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 
 <!--<script>--!>
 <!--Aqui entra el codigo JavaScript--!>
 <!--</script>--!>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, he utilizado este codigo, sin embargo cuando le doy al boton de crear agrega directamente el registro sin mostrar el modal

Comment: Tuve una situación similar y lo solucione, para tu caso, usando el boton Crear para llamar al modal y dentro del modal un botón para que al ejecutarlo haga el submit y cierre en modal.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#exampleModalCenter .btn-primary").click(function(){
    $("form#f").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Te hace falta agregar los ID a los botones para que puedas controlar de mejor manera los eventos y al Button de tu formulario

```
<button type="submit" id="ad" name="add_user" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" >Crear</button>
```

Te recomiendo que el ID y el name sean iguales y cambia el type="submit" por type="button"

```js
$("#modalAdd").click(function() {
  $("#f").submit();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card col-md-6">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <form method="post" id="f" action="add_user.php">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Cedula</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cedula" name="cedula" placeholder="Cedula" required onkeypress="return valida(event)" minlength="7">
                    <div id="Info"></div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Nombre</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="full-name" name="full-name" placeholder="Nombre completo" required onkeypress="return letras(event)">
                  </div>
                  <!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Usuario</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" required>
                    <div id="nfo"></div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Contraseña</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required minlength="8">
                  </div>
                  <!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Rol de Usuario</span>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control" id="level" name="level" required>
                      <option value="">Selecciona el tipo de usuario</option>
                      <?php foreach ($groups as $group ):?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $group['group_level'];?>">
                        <?php echo ucwords($group['group_name']);?>
                      </option>
                      <?php endforeach;?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="btn btn-info">Status Usuario</span>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status" required>
                      <option value="">Selecciona el status del usuario</option>
                      <option value="1">Activo</option>
                      <option value="0">Inactivo</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <!-- ./form-group -->
                  <div class="form-group clearfix" style="float: right;">
                    <button type="button" id="add_user" name="add_user" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Crear</button>
                  </div>
                  <!-- ./form-group -->
                </div>
                <!-- ./col -->
              </form>
            </div>
            <!-- ./panel-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- ./panel default -->
        </div>
        <!-- ./card-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.card -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!--/. container-fluid -->


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">¿Esta seguro de crear el usuario?</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Compruebe que los datos son correctos antes de crear el usuario
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="modalAdd" name="modalAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Crear Usuario</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary "data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

De esta forma cuando den click al button del formulario solo abrira el modal y el button del modal enviara el formulario para ser procesado.