# Confirmar envio de formulario con Modal (bootstrap) en Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap, formularios

Tengo un form para eliminar un registro en laravel, este form esta una tabla donde muestro todos los tags:

```
@foreach($tags as $tag)
  <tr>
  <th scope="row">{{ $tag->id }}</th>
  <td>{{ $tag->name }}</td>
  <td>
    <form action="{{ route('tag.destroy', $tag->id) }}" method="POST">
     @csrf @method('DELETE')
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</button>
    </form>
   </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

en mi modelo:

```
// Remove the specified tag from delete.
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $tags = Tag::find($id);
        $tags->delete();
        return back()->with('status', __('Your tag has been successfully deleted.'));        
    }
```

Me gustaría que cuando pinche en el botón eliminar no elimine directamente, sino que ejecute un modal para confirmar la eliminación. Ejecutar el model se hacerlo, lo que no soy capaz es a recurar el id que quiero eliminar en el modal.

Comment: puedes llamar un modal y indicarle por medio de javascript confirm.
Ejemplo de un modal por medio de javascript es https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/ lo puedes invocar desde el metodo destroy



es muy util.

Comment: Si solo te falta que el form se envíe en caso de que el usuario confirme, agrega todo lo que tengas hecho hasta que abres el modal. Revisa también si la pregunta ya está respondida en el sitio, por ejemplo [Usar modal para confirmar si se crear un usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/186554/usar-modal-para-confirmar-si-se-crear-un-usuario) o [¿Cómo crear un mensaje de confirmación de un formulario?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/221990/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-mensaje-de-confirmaci%C3%B3n-de-un-formulario)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ La primera opción no me sirve, si yo a mi botón le pido abrir un modal, y en ese modal tengo el form, llamo a $tag->id, ya no sabe que id es el que debe eliminar, tiene que eliminar el que corresponde, la segunda opción que propones si es válida, pero por estética, necesito que sea un modal y no un alert. Completo el mensaje añadiendo más información de donde esta situado el botón

Comment: @KinslertVirguez. Lo voy a revisar, suena muy bien, ¿sabes si puedo abrir un modal normal sin que sea con esos estilos?

Comment: los estilos los cargas con el mismo swal si no quieres usar estilo agregas un query con javascript al 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('selector btn').click(function(){
  $('selector al que se le va a eliminar'').removeClass('clase a remover de swal')
tambien si quieres eliminar o cambiar los estilos los puedes hacer directamente desde el mismo archivo de swal.
})
})

Comment: Le agregué a la pregunta la etiqueta de bootstrap, que por las clases que tienen tus etiquetas parece que es lo que estás usando y a lo que te refieres con "modal". Corrígelo si no es así.

Comment: Corregido. Sigo investigando como hacer eso de una manera sencilla en laravel, lo de los alert me vale para notificar, pero en el futuro quiero que para eliminar en el modal te pida que introduzcas el nombre del elemento a borrar para confirmar, así que sigo con la duda como hacerlo en un modal. A ver si alguien me puede ayudar que no sea vuejs

Comment: en realidad no se porque no usar vuejs, es mas simple y sencillo de lo que parece, de igual modo se puede replicar en javascript no se que tanto sepas pero solo es crear el metodo eliminar, para confirmar el campo a eliminar con un input text solo pasarias el nombre de lo que eliminara al modal y un input donde valides que los dos campos coincidan, es cuestion de logica pero en si esto ultimo es lo que buscas??